# demo-magento2.vuestorefront find user name and password

Tags: data-import, vue-storefront

I am new Vuestorefront, I am trying to change  product catalog
for that, everywhere is returning to go admin panel but can anyone tell me how to get the user name and PWD of demo admin panel

http://demo-magento2.vuestorefront.io/admin 
 reference page https://docs.vuestorefront.io/guide/cookbook/data-import.html#_2-1-recipe-a-using-demo
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The Magento demo is purely for demo purposes. If you intend to begin working in Magento on catalog and orders you will need to spin up your own instance of Magento (or desired backend).